# Use gdb for ros control plugin

Tags: ros, roslaunch, gdb, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Somebody who have used gdb to debug a ros control plugin please share some experience with me:)

I added the "launch-prefix="gdb -ex run --args" " attribute in the node tag of my launch file.

But when roslaunch the launch file here is what I got

```
"/opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner": not in executable format: File format not recognized
Starting program:  joint1_effort_controller __name:=controller_spawner __log:=/home/lc/.ros/log/7a02b5fc-3c75-11e6-8071-0023248137eb/rrbot-controller_spawner-1.log
No executable file specified.
```

My gdb version is 7.7.1 and my ubuntu version is 14.04, my ros version is indigo.

And by the way if don't use gdb, is there any other debug tools for debugging a plugin?

Thanks in advance

Erli

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238203/use-gdb-for-ros-control-plugin/) by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `spawner` script is a Python script that invokes some services to load / start / stop / unload your controllers. If you want to debug a controller, I think you'd need to run the process that contains your `controller_manager` and possibly your `hardware_interface` in `gdb`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on 2016-06-28**:
Thank you for your comment, now I know why I have such error.
For debugging a controller in `gdb`, would you mind to describe it in more detail or provides me with some link solving similar question?
Thanks again!

Erli

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-29**:
It should be a matter of determining which node is running your `controller_manager` and then loading *that* node in `gdb` using the `launch-prefix` approach you already found.

**Comment by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on 2016-06-29**:
Great! I think I got your idea, I would try it later.

**Comment by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on 2016-07-09**:
Hi, I tied several ways and finally I can use `gdb` to debug my plugin. I write my experience below.